# Does docker swarm provide high availability?

Tags: docker, high-availability

I've read that `docker swarm` provides load balancing but does it also enable high availability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: Yes it does provide high availability. The cluster can withstand 1 host crashing in a setup with 3 hosts, 2 host crashing on a setup with 5 hosts, 3 hosts crashing on a setup with 7 hosts.....

Check the [official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/1.1/high-availability/set-up-high-availability/) for details.

Comment: Does docker swarm need Docker UCP?

Comment: No it doesnt. Ucp is a ui in docker ee. Docker swarm can be easily startes from the commandline and nodes join. All for free

Comment: Does docker swarm work with any container? Even with a simple container I created?

Comment: Yes. it works with any container but you need to write a compose file. For mor infos please check the documentation I won't be answering anymore